# How can I limit AWS Lex slot prompt retries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I have created an AWS Lex chatbot. In the intent, I created a built-in slot with a prompt. When the slot don't get expected value it asks for the input again and again. I want to limit the slot prompts. e.g. When slot don't get expected input it should stop asking the same slot value after the 2nd retry.

In the documentation, AWS says, by default maxAttemps attribute is set to 2. But it didn't work, it keeps sending the slot prompt. Is there any reason why it isn't working?

I tried to limit the retry attempt in the console but couldnt find it in the lex V2 console.
Any help will be appreciated.
thanks